# Trying to extract a specific row from a data table in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to R and this is my first attempt at Shiny, so please forgive what may be an obvious fix.

I have the following data frame:

```
     ID Bet.Total Point.Total Cash.Value
1  2000  5,741.00   43,264.00      61.81
2  2001 10,009.70   90,087.00     128.70
3  2002 10,875.06   97,177.00     138.82
4  2003  5,754.04   43,658.00      62.37
5  2004  5,771.00   43,860.00      62.66
6  2005  5,097.70   38,743.00      55.35
7  2006  1,605.45   59,402.00      84.86
8  2007  7,430.43   55,995.00      79.99
9  2008 20,960.50  188,645.00     269.49
10 2009 10,626.80   92,209.00     131.73
11 2010 42,711.50  384,404.00     549.15
```

I'm trying to create a Shiny app in which the user can select their ID and the app returns their Bet.Total, Point.Total, and Cash.Value.

Here is my ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Bet Rewards Calculator"),

    fluidRow(
            column(3,
                   selectizeInput("ID", choices = "ID",
                    label = h4("Rewards ID")),
                   br(),
                   actionButton("submit", "Submit")),

            column(7, offset = 2,
                   DT::dataTableOutput("betReport")))

    )
)
```

And here is my server.R code:
    library(DT)

```
betReport <- read.csv("BetReport.csv")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$submit)
    output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({betReport})

# print the selected indices
    output$x2 = renderPrint({
            s = input$ID_rows_selected
            if (length(s)) {
                    cat("This is your balance.")
                    cat(s, sep = ",")
            }
    })

})
```

I have tried various permutations of the server code from simple to complex to return just the corresponding row of data, with no success. When I run this particular code, the app crashes and I get the following error message:
`Error in exprToFunction(handlerExpr, handler.env, handler.quoted) : 
  argument "expr_sub" is missing, with no default`

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are a number of issues. In `server.R` appear `x1`, `x2` and `ID_rows_selected` that don't appear in `ui.R`. The `betReport` output is not defined. It's not clear where the user can select his/her `ID`, since the `choices` argument of the `selectInput` has just one value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what you want your app to do so I'm pretty confident that the solution below doesn't get you fully to your goal but I think it should be close.

The error you get is from `observeEvent(input$submit)` in your `server.R` file. It needs a second argument that is triggered when the event is triggered, and you're not specifying anything. In the code below I've just included everything in your server code and I don't think that is what you want but just to give you an example.

Also, in the `ui.R` file you need to have labels for each element corresponding to the output elements computed in the `server.R` file. The choices are also pretty boring since there's only one possible choice (ID) right now.

However the following two files might get you up and running. At least it will show the data table and respond to input.

The first is `server.R`. Remember to include the line to read in your data and all that.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
                observeEvent(input$submit, {

                output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable(betReport)

                                        # print the selected indices                                                                                                           
                output$x2 = renderPrint({
                    s = input$ID_rows_selected
                    if (length(s)) {
                        cat("This is your balance.")
                        cat(s, sep = ",")
                    } else {
            print("I shouldn't be here but the rows_selected is wrong")
                    }
                })
                                                                                   })

            })
```

The `ui.R` is

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Bet Rewards Calculator"),

    fluidRow(
        column(3,
               selectizeInput("ID", choices = "ID",
                              label = h4("Rewards ID")),
               br(),
               actionButton("submit", "Submit")),

        column(7, offset = 2,
               DT::dataTableOutput("x1"),
               br(),
               textOutput("x2")
               )
        )



    )
        )
```